# File_get_contents returns "..."

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Im trying to scrape information from the site http://steamstat.us - The thing i want to get is the status and such from the site.

Im currently only using this code:

```
<?php 
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.steamstat.us/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

The problem I have here is that "Normal (16h)" and the rest just returns 3 dots.

Cant figure what the problem should be.

Anyone have any clue?

**EDIT**

This is now fixed.
I solved the problem as followed:

```
<?php 
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$json_url = file_get_contents('https://crowbar.steamdb.info/Barney', FALSE, $context);
$data = json_decode($json_url);
?>
```

Comment: _"that "Normal (16h)" and the rest just returns 3 dots"_ the what? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Epodax Check this print https://gyazo.com/d04d5421ac528543ac7e19b25b4624b8 It should return "Normal" but returns that.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Hmm, alright - do you have any clue how to get it from the JS?

Comment: You either need a headless browser which can actually run the Javascript (err, probably not something you want to do), or you need to analyse and pry apart the running site in your browser to see if you can fetch the data from where the Javascript fetches it.

Answer (score -2):

Its a https protocol which is not easy to scrap. Thought the website allows it as the headers sent for "access-control-allow-origin" are marked as * which means the content can be requested by any other site.
You are not receiving the content becasue Normal (16h) is not yet populated on page load. Its coming from ajax. 
The HTML source says `<span class="status" id="repo">…</span>`. You are receiving these three dots inside span tag in file_get_contents.
The only way to do it is to look for the ajax call in the network log and then use file_get_contents in that URL called by ajax.

Comment: HTTPS is not any harder to scrape than HTTP, and the Access-Control header does not hinder scraping in any way either.